# How to get the date when an image was taken from MediaStore if I have the file path?

Tags: android, cursor, android-contentresolver

I know that I can retrieve the id of image using the following code:

```
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };

    String selection = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " = ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { mediaFile.mediaFile().getAbsolutePath() };

    Uri queryUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(queryUri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
    if(cursor!=null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID));
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
```

I wonder, if there is any possible way to `MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA_TAKEN`, `MediaStore.Images.Media.LONGITUDE`, and`MediaStore.Images.Media.LATITUDE` using the same approach?

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have the file path, you can get the date this way:

```
File file = new File(filePath);
if(file.exists()) //Extra check, Just to validate the given path
{
    Date lastModDate = new Date(file.lastModified());    
    Log.i("Dated : "+ lastModDate.toString());//Dispaly lastModDate. You can do/use it your own way
}
```

An alternative option to find this would be from the `EXIF` data of the image, if its available:

```
ExifInterface intf = null;
try 
{
    intf = new ExifInterface(path);
}
catch(IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

if(intf != null)
{
    String dateString = intf.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME);
    Log.i("Dated : "+ dateString.toString()); //Dispaly dateString. You can do/use it your own way
}
```